# PHPMailer - Unable to get full error message

Tags: php, phpmailer

Looking for help with my PHPMailer code if possible please.

Overall, it works fine, what I'm struggling to capture is the specific error messages.

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
 echo "Mail <font color=red><b>Not</font></b> Sent to $address - Error: $mail>ErrorInfo<br>";
 }
else {
 echo "Mail <font color=green><b>Successfully</font></b> Sent to $address<br>";
 }
```

This works okay, but the ErrorInfo I receive for an Invalid address for example is:`You must provide at least one recipient email address`

Whereas if I look in the actual debug log, I can see an actual error:
`Invalid address:  (bcc): steven.rothera.com`

Can anyone help me get it so I can echo the actual error message please?

I've looked at a bunch of other posts to try help me get to the bottom of this but no luck so far.

To cover off some of the code that is present:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
  $fp = fopen('/var/log/phpmailer.log','a');
  fwrite($fp, date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "\t" . $str);
  fclose($fp);
};
```

I have tried to use exceptions also, but this didn't show me any errors:

```
try {
 $mail->send();
  echo 'Message sent!';
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
      } catch (\Exception $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
      }
```

Example end of the debug log to show PHPMailer showing the error but only in debugoutput, not to client:

```
[Tue Nov 14 14:09:44.825753 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 27278] [client 172.*:*] CLIENT -> SERVER: .\r\n
[Tue Nov 14 14:09:44.836228 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 27278] [client 172.*:*] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1C35668092\r\n
[Tue Nov 14 14:09:44.836273 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 27278] [client 172.*:*] CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT\r\n
[Tue Nov 14 14:09:44.840627 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 27278] [client 172.*:*] SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye\r\n
[Tue Nov 14 14:09:44.840837 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 27278] [client 172.*:*] Invalid address:  (to): steven.rothera.com
```

Comment: In the case of an invalid email address, the `addAddress()` method will either throw an exception or return false (depending on the constructor param) before you get as far as calling `send()`, and you will get more accurate error messages by dealing with the errors as they occur instead of waiting until you call `send()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything else so far has been unsuccessful, I instead took an approach to pull that entry from the log, which seems to work, so I'm sharing it for other people's sake.

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
  $emailoutput .= "Mail <font color=red><b>Not</font></b> Sent to $address - <b>Error:</b> $mail->ErrorInfo<br>";
  $emailoutput .= "<b>Further Error Info: </b>";
  $emailoutput .= exec('grep ' . escapeshellarg($address) . ' ' . escapeshellarg('/var/log/phpmailer.log'));
  $emailoutput .= "<br>";
  }
else {
  $emailoutput .= "Mail <font color=green><b>Successfully</font></b> Sent to $address<br>";
  }
echo $emailoutput;
```

To give you an idea of how that looks[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer can only report the errors it knows about i.e. the errors which are returned via SMTP. If your code is not reflecting what the MTA is logging, then the first step would be to look at the SMTP exchange. If the MTA is writing important stuff to the log which it is not telling the client about then your only course of action is to change the MTA - not your code.

Turn the debugging up to 4 and if this still does not answer your question **show us the SMTP exchange**

Comment: PHPMailer is bringing the error through on its debugoutput though, so surely it does know about it?
Debugging to 4 didn't do anything more.
Will add some example logs to the end of the main info

Comment: So your issue is that the MTA is writing stuff you want to see to the log it is not returning to the client.  You can't fix this in your php code.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an updated version of your code with some modifications and additional suggestions for debugging:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // your code to configure PHPMailer
    // Attempt to send the email
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message sent!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // PHPMailer specific exception
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Generic exception
    echo 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Additional Debugging Information
echo 'Debug Output:<br>';
echo nl2br(file_get_contents('/var/log/phpmailer.log'));
```

Make sure to do the following:

- File Permissions
- Check SMTP Conntections

Comment: Can't see much difference in the code from the question, some extra explanation would help.

Comment: Used this interpretation anyway as a test, no change in the outcome.
All I receive is the echo's for the "Message Sent" and no exceptions shown

Comment: echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
 echo 'Full error message:' . PHP_EOL;
 echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

should try this in my case its work

Comment: This seems to be identical to OP's code, except you are *not* setting `SMTPDebug` and `Debugoutput` ... ? Was that intentional, and if so why?

Answer (score -1):

`$mail->ErrorInfo` You can get the error message, try it

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
   // use smtp service
   $mail->isSMTP();
   // send html
   $mail->isHTML();
   // The encoding format is UTF 8. If the encoding is not set, Chinese characters will appear garbled.
   $mail->CharSet = "utf8";
   // sender s smtp server address
   $mail->Host = $host;
   // whether to use authentication
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   // The sender’s email username is the email address used by your own SMTP service.
   $mail->Username = $username;
   // The sender’s email password. Note that the “client authorization password” is filled in here instead of the email login password!
   $mail->Password = $password;
   // use ssl protocol
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
   // the ssl protocol port number is 465
   $mail->Port = 465;
   // Set the sender information, such as the sender in the email format description
   $mail->setFrom($username, $sender_name);
   // Set the recipient information, such as the recipient in the email format description
   $mail->addAddress($toemail, $sender_name);
   // Set the respondent information, which refers to the email address to which the reply email will be sent if the recipient wants to reply after receiving the email.
   $mail->addReplyTo($username, $sender_name);
   // mail title
   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   // email text
   $mail->Body = $body;
   if($mail->ErrorInfo) {
       // failed to send
      return ['code' => 0, 'msg' => $mail->ErrorInfo];
   }
   if(!$mail->send()) {
      // failed to send
      return ['code' => 0, 'msg' => $mail->ErrorInfo];
   }
   // sent successfully
   return ['code' => 1, 'msg' => ''];
```

Comment: I don't believe this does anything different for me? I am able to display the ErrorInfo, but the Error info does not show the info I'm looking for